# Fallo while false

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo el objetivo de que el usuario introduzca su nombre, pero este debe ser mayor de 3 caracteres y menor de 5. El caso es que al ejecutarlo nunca para finaliza el bucle y este vuelve a pedir una y otra vez el nombre

```
    nombre = "0"
verify = len(nombre)> 5 and len(nombre)< 3

while verify == False:
    nombre = str(input("Introduce tu nombre "))
```

Comment: Tienes las comparaciones al reves: `verify = len(nombre) > 3 and len(nombre) < 5`, o, más corto, `verify = len(nombre) == 4`

Comment: Esto no es la respuesta ? por que es un comentario y ya ?

Comment: @Excorpion. No todas las preguntas ameritan una respuesta. En este caso, es un error tan trivial que basta un comentario.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion @CandidMoe :3

Comment: Primero, si lo que deseas es pedirle al usuario que introduzca su nombre y, si este no tiene 4 caracteres exactos, volverlo a pedir hasta que se cumpla esta condición, entonces el bucle debería de ser: `while True:`, dentro de este: `nombre = str(input("Introduce tu nombre "))`, debajo: `if len(nombre) == 4:` y dentro de este if: `break`.

Comment: @Candid Moe será un error trivial pero tu respuesta no solucionó mi pregunta, no como la de Firefly que si lo hizo, lo que para unos es trivial para otros en fase de aprendizaje no resulta tan claro.